# How to parse string which represent a tree-like data structure

Tags: c++, parsing, emv

I need to parse each token contained in the text into a struct of three members like

```
struct token {
    string id;
    int length;
    string value;
};
```

Each token can be identified using it first text (of length 2) (from 00 to 99) which is it's id.
Then the id is followed by a numerical value which represent the length of the value which is the next item followed by the length.

The problem here is some id (token) also represent a collection of tokens with each of their id starting from 00... I have tried to solve it this way...

```
tlv* Decoder::parsetlv(std::string data)
{
    tlv* root = new tlv();

    tlv* tlv_list = root;
    tlv* temp = nullptr;


    for (size_t index = 0; index < data.length(); temp = tlv_list, tlv_list = tlv_list->next) {

        if (!tlv_list) {
            temp->next = new tlv();
            tlv_list = temp->next;
        }


        tlv_list->Id = data.substr(index, 2);
        auto tempId = tlv_list->Id;
        index = index + 2;

        tlv_list->length = data.substr(index, 2);
        index = index + 2;

        int length = atoi(tlv_list->length.c_str());
        tlv_list->value = data.substr(index, length);
        if (any_of(_parentTagsIdentifiers, 72, tlv_list->Id)) {
            //place of horror
            tlv_list->child = tlv_list;

        }
        index = index + length;

    }

    return root;
}
```

Problem I discovered from my implementation is that child id are being confused as parent id, since they have the same id where as the different is that the parent id are under what is called a root id while the child id are under(subsequent of) another id which in this case is called a template id.

Comment: Please use your example input and tell us what is the expected output.

Comment: oh that was a mistake thanks

Comment: Now when I see Qr code parsing it is clear that this was [xy problem](http://xyproblem.info/) and a bit still is. I recommend edit question again describing problem from begging. Starting from that you have some data from Qr code. What is exact format of this data, what this Qr code represents, then what do you expect and what you have.

Comment: @OgunleyeAyowalePius The sample data you provided is not correct.(e.g the length of data is invalid). Could you provide a basic example? Also edit your question for more clarity.

Comment: @MarekR  No this problem does not have anything to do with the Qr it is just a namespace in the provided code anyway, although I plan to generate Qr code in the project but, the main goal is to parse a text of that kind using this spec.  https://github.com/apisit/emv-qr-code-generator/blob/master/Documents/EMVCo-Merchant-Presented-QR-Specification-v1_0.pdf

Comment: @cse I have corrected that thanks...

Comment: @OgunleyeAyowalePius Length part of TLV is in hexadecimal or in decimal?

Answer (score 1):

Following is sample code to break data into TLV format. [See it working here](https://ideone.com/u1yIUg):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <cstdio>
using namespace std;

class TLV
{
    public:

        string tag;
        unsigned int length;
        string value;

        TLV(string data)
        {
            value = "";
            //If there is enough data
            if(data.length() >= 4)
            {
                tag = data.substr(0,2);
                sscanf(data.substr(2,4).c_str(),"%2x",&length);

                //If there is enough data
                if(data.length() >= 4 + length*2) value = data.substr(4,length*2);
            }
        }

        static void parseTLV(string data, vector<TLV*> &res)
        {
            while(data.length() >= 4)
            {
                TLV *t = new TLV(data);
                if(t->value == "") break;
                res.push_back(t);
                data = data.substr(4+(t->length+t->length));
            }

            if(data.length() != 0)
            {
                //Whole data is not in TLV format. Can throw some error
                cout<<"ERROR [1] :: ["<<data<<"]\n";
            }
        }
};


int main()
{
    string data = "0007AAAAAAAAAAAAAA010FAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA0220AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA";
    vector<TLV*> res;
    TLV::parseTLV(data, res);
    for(TLV *t:res)
    {
        printf("%s | %02X | %s |\n",t->tag.c_str(),t->length,t->value.c_str());
    }
    return 0;
}
```